# How to remove an object in a list of map if one of the map values is the same with another map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of maps with 'name' and 'place' values. The case is if map one and map two 'place' value is the same. I want map two to be deleted. With my *exampleList* we can see that map one with the name of *akashi* and place *Japan* then map two have the name *Genta* and place *Japan* too. I want to delete map two, because the place is the same as map one.

```
List exampleList = [
    {
      'name': 'Akashi',
      'place': 'Japan',
    },
    {
      'name': 'Genta',
      'place': 'Japan',
    },
    {
      'name': 'Hinata',
      'place': 'indonesia',
    },
    {
      'name': 'Jinwoo',
      'place': 'Korea',
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `List<String>` to store the unique places and just use it to check if the place already exists or not.

Here is a complete function to filter with the required logic:

```
List filterList(List list, {bool removeAllOccurrences = false}) {
  final List<String> uniquePlaces = [];
  final List filteredList = [];

  for (Map map in list) {
    if (!uniquePlaces.contains(map['place'])) {
      // If it is the first time to see this place

      uniquePlaces.add(map['place']);

      filteredList.add(map);
    } else {
      if (removeAllOccurrences) {
        filteredList.removeWhere((m) => m['place'] == map['place']);
      }
    }
  }

  return filteredList;
}
```

And here is the output of the function performed on your example list:

```
Keeping only one occurrence:
[{name: Akashi, place: Japan}, {name: Hinata, place: indonesia}, {name: Jinwoo, place: Korea}]

Removing all occurrences:
[{name: Hinata, place: indonesia}, {name: Jinwoo, place: Korea}]
```

You can also check [this link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=96e7c491acd3dbe0455c91f70cdb0d40) to get a working example at DartPad.

Comment: but how if i want to delete the first one ?

Comment: I have updated the function and the example in DartPad to include this case, check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [LodashFlutter](https://pub.dev/packages/lodash_flutter) package. In the package, it declares various methods. It's much helpful for you.

You have to use only a single line of code and you get your results.

- uniqBy(List array, key);
- uniq(List array);